# Pass-by-reference and ref

Tags: c#

I have been reading a bit the tutorials on MSDN to get my head around pass-by-reference in C#, `ref` and `out` and I came across the following code sample:

```
using System;

class TheClass
{
    public int x;
}

struct TheStruct
{
    public int x;
}

class TestClass
{
    public static void structtaker(TheStruct s)
    {
        s.x = 5;
    }
    public static void classtaker(TheClass c)
    {
        c.x = 5;
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        TheStruct a = new TheStruct();
        TheClass b = new TheClass();
        a.x = 1;
        b.x = 1;
        structtaker(a);
        classtaker(b);
        Console.WriteLine("a.x = {0}", a.x); //prints 1
        Console.WriteLine("b.x = {0}", b.x); //prints 5
    }
}
```

The note to this from the tutorial:

> This example shows that when a struct is passed to a method, a copy of
>   the struct is passed, but when a class instance is passed, a reference
>   is passed.

I totally understood it, but my question is, if a reference is passed in C# to the parameter, why would they need `ref` as in the following sample:

```
void tearDown(ref myClass a)
{
    a = null;
}

MyClass b = new MyClass();
this.tearDown(ref b);
assert(b == null);
//b is null
```

??? I thought C# was the same in C - pass-by-value.

Comment: Just because it's a reference type, doesn't mean it's passed by reference. Passing is by value unless you explicitly use `ref`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Yes, passing is by value by default, but value that is being passed is a reference itself for reference types.

Comment: The part `MyClass b = new MyClass();` creates 2 pieces of memory: the reference variable `b` and an anonymous instance on the heap. The reference variable behaves exactly like a value type (eg `int`).

Comment: Jeroen, no sir, this is not correct. Objects are passed by reference automatically. To test it, just pass in a mutable object (e.g. a list of strings) as a parameter to a method. Add an item to the list in the method. Then check the list outside of the method, and you will see the list has been modified. This only happens when an object is passed by reference. Reference types (meaning all objects) are automatically passed by, well, reference.

Comment: Your `assert(b == null);` will fail when you remove the `ref`. TearDown() needs the reference by reference.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, but even without the `ref` part as in `classtaker`, `Console.WriteLine("b.x = {0}", b.x);` prints `5`.

Comment: @AnthonyGatlin - Reference types are _not_ passed by reference by default. References are passed by value, which is not the same.

Comment: Under the hood, ref is implemented as a managed pointer. So what ever you *ref*er to, a pointer is passed to it.

Comment: @Lee, yes, you are correct, the reference itself is passed by value--but the object itself is not passed by value.

Comment: In `b.x` the `x` is on the heap and _always_ passes/accessed by reference. By _the_ reference `b`. Draw or find a picture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C#, basically all classes as pointers. However, passing by ref/out or not is like passing the pointer to a pointer or the pointer itself.

When you pass a class (as per the first sample) any changes to the classes *members* are carried over. However, changing the reference to *the object itself* would not yield the results. Say you replace

```
public static void classtaker(TheClass c)
{
    c.x = 5;
}
```

With

```
public static void classtaker(TheClass c)
{
    c = new TheClass();
    c.x = 5;
}
```

Since `c` is not an `out` or `ref` paramter, you're reassigning the local pointer to `c`, not the value of `c` itself. Since you only modified the `.x` of the local `c`, the result would be that `b.x == 1` after calling this modified ClassTaker.

Now, as per your second example, since a is a `ref` parameter, changes to the value a itself will be seen in the calling scope, as in the example, but removing the `ref` from the call would cause the `null` assertion to fail.

Basically, `ref` passing passes what can be thought of as a pointer to your pointer, while calling without `ref`/`out` passes a copied pointer to your object data.

---

EDIT:

The reason one can assign `c.X` in method scope is because the object `c` *points* to the object `X`, and you'll always get the same pointer to `X` regardless of the `ref`/`out` parameter or not. Instead, `ref`/`out` modifies your ability to change the value `c` as seen by the calling scope.

Comment: Here is the link to the [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471(v=vs.71).aspx) , which shows the results. Thanks.

Comment: c.X changes because X is a pointer within the c object, and can be changed from within the method scope regardless of ref.out or not. The ref/out parameters only modify your ability to change the value of c as seen bythe calling scope. I'll integrate this into my answer

Comment: I honestly don't know - I'm more familiar with the behavior of the code than the theory and terminology behind it. To wager a guess, I'm thinking it's because in C#, half the behavior is determined by the definition of the object itself (struct vs. class), rather than the particular method or implementation one desires (as per C++)

Comment: Some jargon fixes: Classes are not pointers, they are Types. Objects are instances of CLasses and are always pointees. References (the pointers) are separate items.